# Postgresql - Foreign Keys falhando

Tags: postgresql

Olá,

Eu tenho uma tabela de VENDA e uma VENDA_ITEM, a ligação entre elas é feita via uma Foreign Key que deleta em cascata e da update em cascata.

Bem, na tabela VENDA_ITEM existe uma trigger que roda no before delete que impede o item de ser deletado se o mesmo já tiver entrega, isto acontece com um RAISE EXCEPTION.

A trigger funciona bem, ao tentar dar um delete from VENDA_ITEM com a trigger habilitada o banco não deleta o item, entretanto ao tentar dar um delete na venda o banco deleta o cabeçalho mas deixa os itens,violando assim a ideia da foreign key, **ou seja, tenho itens sem cabeçalho.**

A estrutura:

```
    create table venda (
    ven_codigo       integer       not null, 
    emp_codigo       integer       not null, 
    usu_codigo       integer       not null, 
    ven_tipo         integer       default 0 not null, 
    vds_codigo       integer       not null, 
    ven_data         date          default current_date not null,
    ven_hora         time          default current_time not null, 
    cli_codigo       integer       not null, 
    fcb_codigo       integer       not null, 
    cpg_codigo       integer       not null, 
    ven_observacao   text, 
    ven_finalizado   integer       default 0, 
    ven_cancelado    integer       default 0, 
    ven_usu_cancel   integer, 
    nf_numero        integer, 
    nf_serie         integer, 
    ven_pdv          integer       default 0 not null, 
    ven_codigo_pdv   integer       default 0 not null, 
    ven_exportadopdv integer       default 0 not null, 
    cliaut_codigo    integer,
    constraint pk_venda primary key (ven_codigo, emp_codigo), 
    constraint fk_venda_empresa  foreign key (emp_codigo) references empresa(emp_codigo)  on update no action on delete restrict, 
    constraint fk_venda_usuario  foreign key (usu_codigo) references usuario(usu_codigo)  on update no action on delete restrict,
    constraint fk_venda_vendedor foreign key (vds_codigo) references vendedor(vds_codigo) on update no action on delete restrict, 
    constraint fk_venda_cliente  foreign key (cli_codigo) references cliente(cli_codigo)  on update no action on delete restrict, 
    constraint fk_venda_forma_cobranca foreign key (fcb_codigo) references forma_cobranca (fcb_codigo) on update no action on delete restrict, 
    constraint fk_venda_condicao_pagamento foreign key (cpg_codigo) references condicao_pagamento (cpg_codigo) on update no action on delete restrict, 
    constraint fk_venda_cliente_autorizado foreign key (cliaut_codigo) references cliente_autorizado (cliaut_codigo) on update no action on delete restrict
    );

    create or replace function sptg_venda_after() returns trigger as $$
declare _sist_sistema integer;
declare _cnf_gerar_carga_web integer;
begin
    if (new.ven_finalizado = 1 or new.ven_cancelado = 1) then
        if (exists(select vi_codigo from venda_itens where ven_codigo = new.ven_codigo limit 1)) then   
            select sist_sistema from sistema limit 1 into _sist_sistema;
            select cnf_gerar_carga_web from configuracao limit 1 into _cnf_gerar_carga_web;

            if (_sist_sistema = 1 and _cnf_gerar_carga_web = 1) then
                insert into carga_web(cargaweb_id, cargaweb_datahora, cargaweb_tabela, cargaweb_codigo, cargaweb_processado)
                values(gen_id(gera_id_carga_web,1), current_timestamp, 'VENDA', new.ven_codigo, 0);
            end if;

        end if;
    end if;

    return new;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';


create trigger tg_venda_after after insert or update on venda
    for each row execute procedure sptg_venda_after();




create table venda_itens (
    vi_codigo            integer        not null, 
    ven_codigo           integer        not null, 
    emp_codigo           integer        not null, 
    pro_codigo           integer        not null, 
    vi_qtde              numeric(18,6)  default 0 not null, 
    vi_valor_vista       numeric(18,6)  default 0 not null, 
    vi_vlr_com_juros     numeric(18,6)  default 0 not null, 
    vi_valor_venda       numeric(18,6)  default 0 not null, 
    vi_comissao          numeric(18,6)  default 0 not null,  
    uni_venda            integer        not null, 
    uni_compra           integer        not null, 
    vi_valor_compra      numeric(18,6)  default 0 not null, 
    vi_conversao_und     numeric(18,6)  default 0 not null, 
    pgr_codigo           integer, 
    vi_qtde_entregue     numeric(18,6)  default 0 not null, 
    vi_qtde_devolvida    numeric(18,6)  default 0 not null, 
    vi_qtde_a_entregar   numeric(18,6)  default 0 not null, 
    vi_descricao_produto varchar(80)    default '' not null, 
    constraint pk_venda_itens primary key(vi_codigo),
    constraint fk_venda_itens_venda foreign key (ven_codigo, emp_codigo) references venda (ven_codigo, emp_codigo) on update cascade on delete cascade, 
    constraint fk_venda_itens_produto foreign key (pro_codigo) references produto (pro_codigo) on update cascade on delete restrict, 
    constraint fk_venda_itens_unidade_venda foreign key (uni_venda) references unidade (uni_codigo) on update cascade on delete restrict, 
    constraint fk_venda_itens_unidade_compra foreign key (uni_compra) references unidade (uni_codigo) on update cascade on delete restrict, 
    constraint fk_venda_itens_unidade_produto_grade foreign key (pgr_codigo) references produto_grade (pgr_codigo) on update cascade on delete restrict 
);


create or replace function sptg_venda_itens_before() returns trigger as $$
declare _ven_cancelado integer; declare _ven_pdv integer;
declare _forma_comissao integer; declare _vds_codigo integer;
begin
    if (TG_OP = 'DELETE') then
        select ven_cancelado, ven_pdv from venda where ven_codigo = old.ven_codigo  and emp_codigo = old.emp_codigo into _ven_cancelado, _ven_pdv;
        if (_ven_cancelado <> 1 and _ven_pdv = 0 and old.vi_qtde_entregue > 0) then
           raise exception 'nao e possivel excluir um item com entregas';
        end if;
    end if;

    if (TG_OP = 'INSERT' or TG_OP = 'UPDATE') then
        select uni_venda, uni_compra, pro_compra, pro_conversao, pro_comissao from produto where pro_codigo = new.pro_codigo
            into new.uni_venda, new.uni_compra, new.vi_valor_compra, new.vi_conversao_und, new.vi_comissao;         
        select vds_codigo from venda where ven_codigo = new.ven_codigo and emp_codigo = new.emp_codigo into  _vds_codigo;
        select cnf_forma_calc_comissao from configuracao limit 1 into _forma_comissao;

        if (_forma_comissao = 0) then
            select cnf_aliq_comissao from configuracao limit 1 into new.vi_comissao;
        else 
            if (_forma_comissao = 1) then
                select vds_comissao from vendedor where vds_codigo = _vds_codigo into new.vi_comissao;
            end if;
        end if;

        new.vi_qtde_a_entregar = new.vi_qtde - new.vi_qtde_entregue;
        if (TG_OP = 'UPDATE' and new.vi_qtde < new.vi_qtde_a_entregar) then                                                
            raise exception 'a quantidade deve ser maior ou igual a quantidade entregue somada a quantidade devolvida';
        end if;
    end if;

    return new;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';



create trigger tg_venda_itens_before before insert or update or delete  on venda_itens
    for each row execute procedure sptg_venda_itens_before();
```

O trecho da trigger que está impedindo (corretamente) a exclusão é o **raise exception 'nao e possivel excluir um item com entregas';**

Estou neste momento implementando meu sistema em PostgreSQL, atualmente ele roda em Firebird  e a ideia final do projeto é que rode nos dois bancos (um ou outro e nao em paralelo).

PS: Estou usando a versão 10.1 do PostgreSQL no Windows 10 x64 Home

Att, Marcos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marcos,

Analisando o seu caso de teste vejo que apesar de contraditório é um comportamento esperado. Veja o que consta na documentação [1]

*"Row-level triggers fired BEFORE can return null to signal the trigger manager to skip the rest of the operation for this row (i.e., subsequent triggers are not fired, and the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE does not occur for this row). If a nonnull value is returned then the operation proceeds with that row value. Returning a row value different from the original value of NEW alters the row that will be inserted or updated. Thus, if the trigger function wants the triggering action to succeed normally without altering the row value, NEW (or a value equal thereto) has to be returned. To alter the row to be stored, it is possible to replace single values directly in NEW and return the modified NEW, or to build a complete new record/row to return. In the case of a before-trigger on DELETE, the returned value has no direct effect, but it has to be nonnull to allow the trigger action to proceed. Note that NEW is null in DELETE triggers, so returning that is usually not sensible. The usual idiom in DELETE triggers is to return OLD."*

Eu fiz testes em todas versoes suportadas inclusive na de desenvolvimento (master) e o comportamento é o mesmo.

Note que ao retornar NEW em uma trigger BEFORE DELETE o NEW é NULL e quando é feito isso você está informando ao "trigger manager" para "pular" as demais verificações... isso tem sido muito utilizado no PostgreSQL por conta do antigo esquema de particionamento de tabelas (apartir da 10 temos particionamento declarativo). Sim, é uma funcionalidade não tão bonita até a 9.6 mas se bem utilizada ajuda bastante.

O próximo passo seria reportar na -hackers esse seu caso de testes para aprofundar melhor o entendimento, porque se realmente for um comportamento esperado então pelo menos precisamos melhorar a documentação, senão corrigir caso realmente seja um erro de fato. Você gostaria de fazer isso ou quer que eu faça??? Afinal vc que descobriu...

Att,

[1] https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: Sinta-se a vontade para fazer, vocês são especialistas no que fazem, não tenho conhecimento o suficiente para argumentar/debater sobre isto, a "descoberta" foi acidental.

Answer (score 1):

Achei o problema, na verdade o sistema não entrava no raise exception, mas sim estava retornando NULL, pois sempre retornava new na trigger, entretando DELETE deveria retornar old.

Entretanto isso me levantou uma certa preocupação, pois uma falha do desenvolvedor quebrou a integridade do banco com as FKs.

Att, Marcos

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo simplificado:

=== Estrutura do banco ===

```
create table cabecalho(
   cab_id          integer     not null,
   cab_nomecliente varchar(50) not null,
   constraint pk_cabecalho primary key(cab_id)
);


create table cabecalho_item(
   cabitem_id          integer      not null,
   cab_id              integer      not null,
   cabitem_nomeproduto varchar(50)  not null,
   constraint pk_cabecalho_item primary key(cabitem_id),
   constraint fk_cabecalho_item_cabecalho foreign key(cab_id) references cabecalho(cab_id) on delete cascade on update cascade
);


create or replace function sptg_cabecalho_item() returns trigger as $$
begin
  return new; --aqui deveria retornar old quando a trigger for delete, ou seja o progrador errou
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';



create trigger tg_cabecalho_item before delete on cabecalho_item
   for each row execute procedure sptg_cabecalho_item();


insert into cabecalho values(1,'MARCOS');
insert into cabecalho values(2,'JOAO');
insert into cabecalho values(3,'FABIO');

insert into cabecalho_item values(1, 1, 'PRODUTO MARCOS 1');
insert into cabecalho_item values(2, 1, 'PRODUTO MARCOS 2');
insert into cabecalho_item values(3, 1, 'PRODUTO MARCOS 3');


insert into cabecalho_item values(4, 2, 'PRODUTO JOAO 1');
insert into cabecalho_item values(5, 2, 'PRODUTO JOAO 2');
insert into cabecalho_item values(6, 2, 'PRODUTO JOAO 3');

insert into cabecalho_item values(7, 3, 'PRODUTO FABIO 1');
insert into cabecalho_item values(8, 3, 'PRODUTO FABIO 2');
insert into cabecalho_item values(9, 3, 'PRODUTO FABIO 3');
```

---

```
delete from cabecalho_item where cab_id = 2;
```

> R:   DELETE 0
>        Query returned successfully in 165 msec.

Ou seja, nao deletou os itens mas não retornou erro algum.

---

```
delete from cabecalho where cab_id = 1
```

> R:   DELETE 1
>        Query returned successfully in 72 msec.

---

Ao selecionar temos o cabeçalho 2 e 3, mas continuamos tendo itens para o cabeçalho 1, 2 e 3, ou seja, violando a integridade da FK.

Answer (score -1):

Marcos,

Você poderia montar um caso de testes mais resumido (reduzindo o modelo) com o estritamente necessário para evidenciarmos a falha? Seria importante no caso de testes ter os devidos DML (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) que nos levem a essa falha pois vc pode sim estar enfrentando um bug.

Com um caso de testes podemos executar ele em diferentes versões para poder entender quando e como a falha surgiu.

Obrigado!

Comment: poste um comentário ao invés de uma resposta.